# How to save the input data into model and then store it in a session for later display using MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am currently working on a project that requires me to save the users input data for his/her delivery address, save it into a session. I need to have the data stored in a session, because I need to display this data later on, in my Thank You page.

Here is my model

```
public class DeliveryAddressModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the first address line")]
    [Display(Name = "Line 1")]
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Line 2")]
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Line 3")]
    public string Line3 { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a city name")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a state name")]
    public string State { get; set; }

    public string Zip { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a country name")]
    public string Country { get; set; }
```

Here is my View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>DeliveryAddressModel</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Line1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Line1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Line1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Line2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Line2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Line2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Line3, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Line3, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Line3, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.State, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.State, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Zip, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Zip, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Zip, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Country, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Country, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Country, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GiftWrap, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GiftWrap)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GiftWrap, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

My controller

```
public class DeliveryAddressController : Controller
{
    // GET: DeliveryAddress
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Address(DeliveryAddressModel dam)
    {


        Session["Name"] = dam.Name;
        Session["Line1"] = dam.Line1;
        Session["Line2"] = dam.Line2;
        Session["Line3"] = dam.Line3;
        Session["City"] = dam.City;
        Session["State"] = dam.State;
        Session["Zip"] = dam.Zip;
        Session["Country "] = dam.Country;

        return View(dam);
    }

}
```

How will I need to make my controller to store the data, for later use? If there is any other way that's easier, let me know. I am new to MVC.

Comment: Can you use JavaScript and save it in localStotage?

Comment: Anything will be fine, as long as I can display the Delivery address on the "Thank you" page.

Comment: So ... save it in the session? What have you tried?

Comment: this is a new try for me. In the previous try I used a SQL database model where the values get submitted, but I had problems that my session does not get populated. So I did research and most of the things I get Is that I do not need a table in SQL so this is what I have tried sofar. Just need help to save the user input data, for later use as I want to dislay the data entered by the user on another page

Answer (score 0):

Initialize DeliveryAddressModel object based on the View results you had up there.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(DeliveryAddressModel dam)
{
    //Set this to the results sent back from your controller.

    Session["Name"] = dam.Name();
    Session["Line1"] = dam.Line1();
    Session["Line2"] = dam.Line2();
    Session["Line3"] = dam.Line3();
    .
    .
    .
    Session["Country "] = dam.Country();
    return View();
}
```

Then you can access the Session object until the user closes their browser.

In your Thank You page View you can access the Session by:

```
@Session["Country"]
```

Comment: All this will be in a controller right? will the controller method be [httppost]? and how will the action look like to add the data to the model when submit is clicked? thanks for your answer

Comment: Yes this is in the controller.  I added pseudo code for that. Your view needs to Post data to the controller. They can have the same method name such as 'UserSignUp'. You could post your controller code to make it a little easier.

Comment: I added my controller. I Am stuck on what to do next.

Comment: I mean, I'm not sure if you're trying to persist data into a database or just experimenting with Sessions. With the update I posted you can access the data submitted from the user. Put @Session["Country"] somewhere in your View to see how it works.

Comment: with the controller I posted above, when I enter the @Session["Country"] nothing appears in the view. I just want the data entered by the user to be there until he exits. Not trying to put it into a database.

Comment: I only need the data that the user enter to display the order summary at the Thank You page if that makes sense

Comment: Have you tried creating a ViewModel class with the properties? Set them in the controller and pass it back when you return View(viewModel); You also need to declare at the top of view page, the model type e.g. @model MyViewModelClass